# Conexão .dbml - Visual Studio 2017 ( C# + SQL Server 2016)

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

No Visual Studio 2012, havia uma opção de criar o arquivo de conexão com o DB em (Add > new Item ) e dai escolher o arquivo de extensão dbml.
No Visual studio 2017, aonde fica?
Me lembro que é algo com (Connection for SQL).

obs. Não adianta eu escolher qualquer classe e alterar a extensão por o script de conexão não será gerado assim como no VS 2012.

Alguém me ajuda?
Obrigado!

Comment: Dê certo @Jonatas?

Answer (score 2):

Se for o `Linq To SQL Class` para criar uma camada `ORM` `SQL Server` siga a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

na verdade nada mudou para criação desse arquivo está a mesma coisa.

Comment: Consegui... No meu caso, necessitei adicionar via instalador no Visual Studio, após foi liberado na adição de referencias.

Comment: @Jonatas se foi útil para você pode marca como resposta